# (10210) Attribute identifier invalid or not supported

Tags: c++, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, soci

We are running snowflake ODBC driver on Linux and  connect using soci ODBC but getting following error .Any idea how to resolve this ?

```
2022-01-05T05:07:26.539 TRACE 1954 Simba::Snowflake::SFConnection::SFConnection: +++++ enter +++++
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.541 TRACE 1954 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.541 INFO  1954 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: Attribute: Unknown Attribute (1061)
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.541 TRACE 1954 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionState::SQLSetConnectAttr: +++++ enter +++++
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.541 TRACE 1954 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionAttributes::SetAttribute: +++++ enter +++++
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.541 INFO  1954 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionAttributes::SetAttribute: Invalid attribute: 1061
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.544 ERROR 1954 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLSetConnectAttr: [Snowflake][ODBC] (10210) Attribute identifier invalid or not supported: 1061
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.544 TRACE 1954 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLDriverConnectW: +++++ enter +++++
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.544 TRACE 1954 Simba::ODBC::ConnectionState2::SQLDriverConnectW: +++++ enter +++++
    2022-01-05T05:07:26.545 ERROR 1954 Simba::ODBC::Connection::SQLDriverConnectW: [Snowflake][ODBC] (10360) Invalid connection string.
```

Here is the connection string

```
soci::session sql("odbc","DRIVER=/x01/uer/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so;SERVER=test.snowflakecomputing.com;PORT=433;DATABASE=VWH_DEV;UID=APP_DEV;PWD=*******");
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @FelipeHoffa 
soci::session sql("odbc","DRIVER=/x01/uer/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so;SERVER=test.snowflakecomputing.com;PORT=433;DATABASE=VWH_DEV;UID=APP_DEV;PWD=*******");

Comment: can you try the string with a prefix "odbc", as in ` sql("odbc","ODBC;DRIVER=/x01/uer/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so;SERVER=test.snowflakecomputing.com;PORT=433;DATABASE=VWH_DEV;UID=APP_DEV;PWD=*******");`

Comment: No luck , still same :/

Comment: what version of the driver are you using?

Comment: Latest version : 2.24.4

Comment: Have you tried using a DSN? Like: **connection_parameters parameters("odbc", "DSN=mydb");
parameters.set_option(odbc_option_driver_complete, "0" /* SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT */);
session sql(parameters);**

Comment: @Sergiu yes I tired, same error

Comment: One last test if you can try: **backend_factory const&amp; backEnd = odbc;
session sql(backEnd, "filedsn=c:\\my.dsn");**.

Answer (score 0):

According to the internet [A](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/535705?language=en_US), [B](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Oracle-ODBC-connection-fails-after-upgrade), [C](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/42649927.2060005@clacorp.com) and [this PDF](http://file:///C:/Users/Simeon/Downloads/odbc-unicodeaccess1.pdf)

You linux box is using `SQLSetConnectAttr` to set attribute 1061 SQL_ATTR_APP_WCHAR_TYPE which defaults to `SQL_DD_CP_UTF16` as used by windows, but linux uses `SQL_DD_CP_UTF8`

Thus, snowflake does not support changing that, like it seems many other DB's don't.

Skimming the PDF has some details, that I think reading will help you.